# Apply Jquery DataTables plugin to ASP GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I've used this plugin before in PHP so I thought I'll use it again for my ASP project.

For some reason it doesn't work with my GridView control.

javascript block:

```
<link type="text/css" href="../scripts/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".gvv").dataTable();
        });
        </script>
```

Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Prop_No" DataSourceID="testtt" CssClass="gvv">
```

Am I doing something wrong or DataTables can't be used for ASP controls?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is that GridView control doesn't add `<thead>` element but just put the header row into `<body>` section of generated table whereas the Data Table plugin requires a `<thead>` section in a table. Try to use following script:

```
$(function () {
    $(".gvv").prepend( $("<thead></thead>").append( $(this).find("tr:first") ) ).dataTable();
});
```

P.S. also you can use controls those don't rendering with default layout like Repeater or ListView

Comment: It works! I don't think I fully understand how, but it does. You got some sick skills there buddy. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer + explanation. This was killing me.

Comment: Don't use "this" in $("#Grid").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTa‌​ble(); coz it gives problems if there is another table already present in the markup b4 "Grid". Instead use $(#Grid) .. So use like this $("#Grid").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("#Grid").find("tr:first"))).dat‌​aTable();

Answer (score 17):

You can add `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` tags using GridView Prerender event try this code

```java
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // You only need the following 2 lines of code if you are not 
  // using an ObjectDataSource of SqlDataSource
  GridView1.DataSource = Sample.GetData();
  GridView1.DataBind();

  if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0) {
   //This replaces <td> with <th> and adds the scope attribute
   GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;

   //This will add the <thead> and <tbody> elements
   GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

   //This adds the <tfoot> element. 
   //Remove if you don't have a footer row
   GridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
  }

}
```

Don't forget to add the event handler on source page as below

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="gvv"
      OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender">
</asp:GridView>
```

Now you can simply call JQuery function as usual to render it

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".gvv").dataTable();
});
```

Comment: You use .gvv instead of .GridView1??

Comment: @JoshYates1980 : Its just forget to define the class name. I have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use "this" in $("#Grid").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable(); coz it gives problems if there is another table already present in the markup b4 "Grid". 
Instead use $(#Grid) .. So use like this $("#Grid").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("#Grid").find("tr:first"))).dataTable();

Comment: Thank you for the great hint

Comment: Thank you  for the great hint

Comment: All works except for the striping of the table rows and some misc. the "odd" and "even" styles are completely ignored and there are no errors.