# Display SqlDataSource data in HTML table (DataTables Plugin)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datatables, append

I want to display SQL Server data in a table `<td>` so I can use the plugin at https://datatables.net/ I am able to bind the data to things such as

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

such as in this tutorial: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-data-from-database-in-HTML-table-in-ASPNet.aspx

However, the plugin needs a class and id from a table, and therefore doesn't work. I tried inserting class and id that the plugin needs like this but did not work

```
// Table start.
html.Append("<table border = '1'>");
html.Append("<table class = "display" id = "example">");
```

Is there a way of inserting a class and id to the table through `html.append`?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a GridVIew? That is a table in html.

Comment: I also tried gridView but that also didnt work, maybe i was referencing the class and id incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a GridView, you need to use the ClientID. Place the below GridView and JavaScript on the same aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

However, for a GridView to work with DataTables, you need to add a `OnRowDataBound` event. Then in code behind add the following code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```

This add the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags to the generated html, which is needed by datatables.net.

Comment: how would I reference the table id and class, if that is just the rows?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. You can set the class with `CssClass` in the GridView. And rows with `RowStyle-CssClass`

Answer (score 0):

I found this that also explained that i needed `<thread>` tags which i was missing.

[Apply Jquery DataTables plugin to ASP GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200681/apply-jquery-datatables-plugin-to-asp-gridview)